# How to get Avro schema validation to support field aliases?

Tags: java, schema, avro

I have renamed a field in a record serialised with Avro. I want to support reading the old versions of the data, without a schema registry. Therefore I keep all versions of the schema as resources loaded from the classpath.

This works great and supports schema evolution. I can read data serialised with the old schemas when they are backward compatible. As part of ensuring this I want to verify the schemas when the application starts. Unfortunately the schema validation does not honour field aliases, even when the decoding data does.

Here is a simple example that proves my point:

```
import java.util.Collections;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder;
import org.apache.avro.SchemaValidationException;
import org.apache.avro.SchemaValidatorBuilder;


public class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchemaValidationException {
        Schema stringType = SchemaBuilder.builder().stringType();
        Schema s1 = SchemaBuilder.builder().record("foo").fields()
                .name("test1").type(stringType).noDefault()
                .endRecord();
        Schema s2 = SchemaBuilder.builder().record("foo").fields()
                .name("test2").aliases("test1").type(stringType).noDefault()
                .endRecord();

        new SchemaValidatorBuilder().canReadStrategy().validateLatest().validate(s2, Collections.singleton(s1));

    }
}
```

This throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaValidationException: Unable to read schema: 
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "foo",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "test1",
    "type" : "string"
  } ]
}
using schema:
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "foo",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "test2",
    "type" : "string",
    "aliases" : [ "test1" ]
  } ]
}
    at org.apache.avro.ValidateMutualRead.canRead(ValidateMutualRead.java:70)
    at org.apache.avro.ValidateCanRead.validate(ValidateCanRead.java:40)
    at org.apache.avro.ValidateLatest.validate(ValidateLatest.java:51)
    at Bar.main(Bar.java:18)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sorry to answer my own question:*

I discovered a variation of this asked but not answered on the Arvo user mailing list. [Different behavior between SchemaValidator and SchemaCompatibility regarding aliased field](https://sematext.com/opensee/m/Avro/F2svI12M0O31fDOyR1?subj=Different%20behavior%20between%20SchemaValidator%20and%20SchemaCompatibility%20regarding%20aliased%20field)

> To me it looks like SchemaValidator has a bug, yet I don't get why there's
>   both SchemaValidator  and SchemaCompatibility so it feels like I'm missing
>   something.

In short use `SchemaCompatibility.checkReaderWriterCompatibility` instead of `SchemaValidatorBuilder` it seams to be more complete and reuses the decoding logic.